# How to switch between system keyboard and my own custom keyboard to use across others apps in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, keyboard

I create my custom keyboard using flutter framework and i used it for my app but i need use this is custom keyboard as system keyboard to use it for others apps in my phone.
How to do that using flutter??

I Found native ways to do that like as input method editor but i need cross way to do